I am unalbe to set background Image to a fabric js canvas in react and next js
I am working on a project where I am using fabricjs with nextjs. I am trying to add a background image to the canvas but it does not show the image.
I also tried fabricCanvas.set("backgroundImage", backgroundImage) but it also did not work.
here is my code:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';
import * as fabric from 'fabric';

const CanvasArea = forwardRef(({ mockup, backgroundImage, onTextObjectSelected }, ref) => {
  const fabricCanvasRef = useRef(null);
  const fabricCanvasInstance = useRef(null);

  // Default images based on the selected mockup category
  const defaultImages = {
    shirt: '/images/shirt1.png',
    cup: '/images/cup1.png',
    frame: '/images/frame1.png',
    bag: '/images/bag1.png',
    pillow: '/images/pillow1.png',
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    addText(type) {
      const text = new fabric.Text(
        type === 'heading' ? 'Heading' : type === 'subheading' ? 'Subheading' : 'Body Text', 
        {
          left: 50,
          top: 50,
          fontSize: type === 'heading' ? 32 : type === 'subheading' ? 24 : 16,
          fontWeight: type === 'heading' ? 'bold' : 'normal',
        }
      );
      fabricCanvasInstance.current.add(text).setActiveObject(text);
      fabricCanvasInstance.current.renderAll();
    },
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!fabricCanvasInstance.current) {
      // Initialize the Fabric.js canvas
      const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(fabricCanvasRef.current, {
        width: 616,
        height: 464,
      });
      fabricCanvasInstance.current = fabricCanvas;

      // Set default background image
      const initialImage = backgroundImage || defaultImages[mockup];
      fabric.Image.fromURL(initialImage, (img) => {
        img.set({
          scaleX: fabricCanvas.width / img.width,
          scaleY: fabricCanvas.height / img.height,
          originX: 'left',
          originY: 'top',
        });
        fabricCanvas.setBackgroundImage(img, fabricCanvas.renderAll.bind(fabricCanvas));
      });

      // Handle object selection
      fabricCanvas.on('selection:created', (e) => {
        const selectedObject = e.target;
        if (selectedObject && selectedObject.type === 'text') {
          onTextObjectSelected(selectedObject);
        }
      });

      fabricCanvas.on('selection:updated', (e) => {
        const selectedObject = e.target;
        if (selectedObject && selectedObject.type === 'text') {
          onTextObjectSelected(selectedObject);
        }
      });
    } else if (backgroundImage) {
      // Update the background image without resetting the canvas
      fabric.Image.fromURL(backgroundImage, (img) => {
        img.set({
          scaleX: fabricCanvasInstance.current.width / img.width,
          scaleY: fabricCanvasInstance.current.height / img.height,
          originX: 'left',
          originY: 'top',
        });
        fabricCanvasInstance.current.setBackgroundImage(img, fabricCanvasInstance.current.renderAll.bind(fabricCanvasInstance.current));
      });
    }
  }, [backgroundImage, mockup, onTextObjectSelected]);

  return (
    <div className="relative shadow-md">
      <canvas ref={fabricCanvasRef} />
    </div>
  );
});

export default CanvasArea;

Did some researches and the function do exist in the documentation, but for some reason does not show up for me.
Your help will be appreciated. Thanks
